# jquery after click

Tags: jquery, callback, click

Is there anyway of checking that an block element remains empty after a click event? Because I need to add some data if the `li` remains empty after the click

```
$('.order_list li').click(function() {
      $('#search_block').remove();
      if( ! $('#search_block').exists()) {
           $(this).html(search_box);
...
```

`exists` its a custom function that I found on stackoverflow as answer

### UPDATE

Because of `$(this).html(search_box);` the li's content is replaced with an input box, but I want to set another text after the user clicks on another li, without having selected nothing before.

### UPDATE2

`.exists()` is not the problem, the problem is when user click another li and the li above remains empty

```
$.fn.exists = function () {
    return this.length !== 0;
}
```

### UPDATE3

The problem http://jsfiddle.net/vsJ96/1/

Comment: How come the same block will exist after its removal?

Comment: Who can add elements to the element?

Comment: Are you looking for text or for children?

Comment: And by the way the `exist` function  used here in SO, is really stupid, it's really not helping at all!

Comment: That code is impossible, if you remove a div, it will never be there. If you do $('#search_block').empty() on the other hand, that would work.

Comment: there are various li's, that removal if to remove the search input so it won't append it self over and over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
$('#search_block').length
```

is easier.

but If you want to know that `$('#search_block')` has some content or not then

```
$('#search_block').contents().length
```

Comment: Please check my question's update, I might've not explained myself well enough

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to see if an element exists, you only need to check the length property:

```
if ( $('#search_block').length ) {

}
```

If you are looking to see if anything exists inside of an element (e.g. for children elements or text nodes), you can check the length of the content:

```
if ( $('#search_block').contents().length ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rbzzq/1/

```
$('body').on( 'click', 'body:has( #search_block ) .order_list li', function() {
    $('#search_block').remove();
    $(this).html(search_box);
});
```